# How to show a dialog notification in Android instead of only appear in notification center?

Tags: android, push-notification

I did an app that receive push notification, but the notification only show in the notification center.

But I saw that when I received a message from whatsapp, it popup a big dialog even I closed the app.

How does it possible?

Some screenshots:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-8WTQisLNIL0/T_O_InFxr6I/AAAAAAAACA4/fdh10K0W79s/s1600/PrtScn20120704114902.jpg

http://www.whatsappen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/popup21.jpg

https://lh4.ggpht.com/Mopo8Uwh3u7mAOqh7_1LBnquLLVe_TaZfeRfZiBx3QoohOVv9qEm1TUNXUEx5MRKrrs=h900

Answer (score 0):

First create a broadcast receiver class by extending BroadcastReceiver and declare it in manifest with intent filter broadcast action. Create an activity and cal only dialog it its onCreate method.Override the onReceive method of broadcast receiver class and call the activitty there. Declare the activity in manifest with

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

In your notification code braocast the intent with specific braodcast action